# Replace class name of second identical class of div element

Tags: php

I am generating a set of div having the same class name. I'm trying to replace the class name of the second div only.

I have used preg_replace but it is replacing all div tags with the bar class name instead of only the class name of the second div, as seen below.

```php
function add_menuclass($mynewclass) {
    return preg_replace('/<div /', '<div class="bar"', mynewclass);
}
```

I have:

```html
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
```

I want:

```html
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
```

Comment: [Please don't use regexes to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/965834). Use a [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) parser instead.

Comment: As above, look into using [DOM Document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and you'll find better programmatic access to the structure of a HTML document.

Comment: I assume you're not generating this HTML yourself in PHP?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm not sur what you mean. I guess I forgot to mention I using WP.

Comment: @Jeto, thank you for the links. I'm unfamiliar with DOM parser. I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the warning @Jeto , is there a way to target this second div and change it into another tag element like a or p ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved part of the problem by doing (for WP):

```
function replace_class($content){
    $html = str_get_html($content);
    $html -> find('div.bar', 1) -> class = 'foo';
    return $html;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'replace_class');
```